# stuck in a selected option

Tags: selection-tools

I'm new to blender and somehow I got into some mode or something (not sure what or how) but I can't find a way out of it. there is a constant orange dot in object mode (even if I press <kbd>A</kbd> to deselect everything) and if I change to edit mode a blue line around the object appears(pic) and nothing else except within that selection can't be adjusted or selected. how do I get out of this selection?

thanks

[image: this is what it looks like in edit mode]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This orange dot is the origin of the object which will be visible in all modes (Object, edit and pose(armatures) modes), so it's not the vertex, as shown below:

[image]

If you press <kbd>A</kbd> to select all vertices then you will find the vertices highlighted as shown below:

[image]

You can select 1 vertex using RightClick then move it using <kbd>G</kbd> as shown below:

[image]

The edges are blue because they are marked. There are five types of markings you can apply to edges. The following is the basic colour scheme:

- **Red** - UV seam
- **Pink** - Edge crease
- **Blue** - Sharp edge
- **Green** - Freestyle edge
- **Orange** - Bevel weight

To clear the mark edges yourself from Edit Mode, go to the Edge menu (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd>) then choose `Clear Sharp` as shown below:
[image]

Then edges will be orange again as normal as shown below:
[image]

Comment: I'm still unable to unselect everything even when I press 'A' there is still one orange dot which turns into the blue selection in edit mode

Comment: @Sam could you provide your .blend file on https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com to be able to help you?

Comment: @Tak [<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=3154" />](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/3154/)

I'm not sure if it's an issue with cell fracture, but I tried making a new project from scratch and the exact issue came again after using cell fracture

Comment: @Sam answer updated

Comment: @tak ok so how do I get rid of this so I can select and edit all the pieces again without there being a blue line etc?

Comment: thanks for your help @Tak I was thinking about this in the wrong way but you have helped clarify